# 圧縮ファイルの展開をundoしたい

Tags: linux, tar

このようなディレクトリ構造で、

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   └── baz
└── foo.tar.gz
```

圧縮ファイルの展開結果と同名のディレクトリ `foo` に気付かず展開コマンド `tar -xf foo.tar.gz` を実行してしまい、`foo` 以下に元々あったファイルと新しく展開されたファイルが混ざってしまいました。（実際はもう少したくさんのファイルと深いディレクトリ構造があります。）

混ざってしまうとマズいので展開してしまったファイルだけ削除したいのですが、どのようにすると手っ取り早いでしょうか？

なお、ファイルが上書きされてしまうと戻せない気がしますが、`foo.tar.gz` を別の場所で展開して自分の記憶と照合する限り同名ファイルは無いように思うので、上書きは無いものと仮定して頂いて構いません。同名ディレクトリはありました。また、もし上書きの可能性まで検出できるような方法があればそれもあると嬉しいです。

#### 環境

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Bash

Comment: バックアップから戻すしかないのでは？　同一名称のファイルがあると既に上書きされ済みなので。

Comment: 展開時のコマンドは`tar xzf foo.tar.gz`の間違いですかね？`.tar.gz`を`tar`で直接扱うなら`-z`が足りないです。

Comment: @cubick 実は現代的な `tar` コマンドは勝手に解析して `.tar.gz` だと認識してくれるので、今回オプションは `-xf` だけで足りました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu なるほど、自分は普段"枯れた"環境(RHEL)に居るのでバージョンによって違ったわけですね。

Comment: @774RR 全くその通りで、投稿後に上書きの可能性に気付き青ざめました。幸運なことに今回元のtarファイルを眺めるにおそらく同名ファイルは無いようなので、上書きの可能性は除去して頂いて大丈夫です（良かった……）（同名ディレクトリはありました）。このことを今から追記します。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

上書きは無いと仮定するなら、アーカイブに含まれるファイル一覧(`tar tf`)の出力結果を元に、
そのファイルを削除する方法はどうでしょうか。

```
$ tar tzf foo.tar.gz | grep -v '/$' | xargs rm
```

リストの内、末尾が`/`で終わるものはディレクトリ名なはずなので、こちらは安全のため敢えて除外しています。中身が空な事を確認して不要であれば削除した方が良いかなと思いました。

Answer (score 6):

tarの操作とそれ以前の操作に時間があいていれば、例えば直前の10分に変更されたファイルを削除することはできます。

```
$ find foo -cmin -10 -type f | xargs rm
```